# C++ makefile install: start program at boot and reboot

Tags: linux, makefile, startup

I'm having trouble understanding a c++ makefile. The makefile is enabling startup of the program at reboot. What I want is that it is enabling startup of the program at boot and reboot. I also want to add the hostname (because that's the paramater that the program needs).

What i tried:

- Add $(shell hostname) to PROGN
- Add $(shell hostname) to the line: cp /etc/... in @test -s reboot

But because I'm having trouble understanding these lines, it is just guessing..

Install part of makefile:

```
PROGN=myProgram

setup:
@install -m 755 -d \
    $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin \
    $(DESTDIR)/etc/$(PROGN)/samples \
    $(DESTDIR)/etc/udev/rules.d
@cp bin/$(PROGN) $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin
@cp sample_profiles/* $(DESTDIR)/etc/$(PROGN)/samples
@cp udev/$(PROGN).rules $(DESTDIR)/etc/udev/rules.d
@test -s /usr/bin/systemd-run && \
    install -m 755 -d $(DESTDIR)$(SYSTEMDDIR)/system && \
    cp systemd/$(PROGN)-reboot.service $(DESTDIR)$(SYSTEMDDIR)/system

install: setup
@test -s /etc/$(PROGN)/profile || \
    cp /etc/$(PROGN)/samples/group_keys /etc/$(PROGN)/profile
@test -s /etc/$(PROGN)/reboot || \
    cp /etc/$(PROGN)/samples/all_off /etc/$(PROGN)/reboot
@udevadm control --reload-rules
@test -s /usr/bin/systemd-run && \
    systemctl daemon-reload && \
    systemctl enable $(PROGN)-reboot
```

Comment: If you remove the @ leading the commands, you will see what commands make is running in your terminal. Thus making it easier to see what is going on and debug (or see your changes).

Comment: Configuration of program start via Makefile is not related to C or C++. You might think about removing these tags.

Comment: @Gerhardh: The makefile is for a C program, i thought it was handy to know what kind of makefile you're dealing with

Comment: It does not really matter how the binary is created. For your issue only the further handling is relevant. This is only a Makefile and Linux issue.

Comment: allright, I romoved the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem of autoboot by startup by removing the last @test part and calling the script in the rc.local file (raspbian jessie lite). The reason I deleted the last part of the makefile is because when i did the install , it would boot the program to set a default setup, but i deleted that part in the code and the install froze.